# How to display list divider in navigation?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Hi everyone how to display the list divider in navigation drawer after each list. I have been trying since from 3 hours couldn't get how to do it?

Comment: Divider after each list or each list items???

Comment: @clairvoyant each list items

Comment: There is no Divider in the navigation drawer

Comment: @Abdellah we have dividers. please check the link http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dividers.html#dividers-types-of-dividers

Comment: What sort of divider you want a space or a line?? If you want a line what you can do is in your adapter layout add a view in last which can act as a line.

Comment: @Clairvoyant it doesn't work. I have added the list view in the last but couldn't get it.

Comment: I am not saying to add listview as the last view. Are you using custom adapter or default adapter to show list items.

Comment: I am using the custom adapter @Clairvoyant

Comment: ok then in you adapter class where you are inflating the layout for listitems in that layout add a view which act as a line like `<View layout_width="match_parent" layout_height="1dp" layout_background="#000000"/>`

Comment: Thanks @Clairvoyant you saved my day.

Comment: Should I paste it as answer so you can accept and question doesn't remain unanswered.